# Can't request audio/video IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a problem based on a code that I used to request audio/video , it works on chrome , mozilla firefox however in IE11 It doesn't work.

I've already read this one:

https://github.com/addyosmani/getUserMedia.js

and applied most of the changes to make it work on IE11 , however I don't get the results, what is wrong in my code that is not allowing me to get the video on that browser.

```
function initiateMedia(obj){
    constraint="";

    if(obj.video=="true" && obj.audio=="true"){
        constraint={
                audio:true,
                video:{
                    width:{max:380},
                    height:{max:260}
                    }

            }
        //Set Video Element
        $("#mediacontainer").html('<video id ="io-videocam" muted="muted"></video>');
        mediactrl = document.querySelector('video');
        mediaType="video/webm";
        return "Audio and Video input found! You can now start recording!";

    }else if(obj.video=="null" && obj.audio=="true"){ //audio input only
        constraint={audio:true, video: false}

        //Set Audio Element
        $("#mediacontainer").html('<audio id ="io-audio" controls muted="muted"></audio>');
        mediactrl = document.querySelector('audio');
        mediaType="audio/mpeg";
        return ("Audio input found! You can now start recording!");

    }else if(obj.video=="null" && obj.audio=="null"){ //no audio or video input
        console.log("No Audio or Video input found");
        return false;
    }

}


function listUserMedia(){

    if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices) {
        console.log("enumerateDevices() not supported.");
        return;
    }

    var media = navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();

    media.then(function(devices) {

        var useVideo=null;
        var useAudio=null;
        devices.forEach(function(device) {

            //console.log(device.kind + ": " + device.label + " id = " + device.deviceId);

            if(device.kind=="audioinput"){
                useAudio="true";

            }

            if(device.kind=="videoinput"){
                useVideo="true";

            }

        });

        if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
            sessionStorage.setItem('useAudio', useAudio);
            sessionStorage.setItem('useVideo', useVideo);
        } else {
            console.log("Unable to set SessionStorage");
        }

    });

    media.catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err.name + ": " + err.message);
    });

    if(typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {

        return {"audio":sessionStorage.getItem('useAudio'),"video":sessionStorage.getItem('useVideo')};
    } else {
        console.log("Unable to get SessionStorage");
    }

    return null;
}


navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;

function requestMedia(string){

if(typeof MediaRecorder === 'undefined' || !navigator.getUserMedia){

        alert('MediaRecorder/getUserMedia no supported on your browser, kindly use Firefox 36+');
    }else{

        //initiateMedia(listUserMedia());
        //navigator.getUserMedia(constraint, startRecording, errorCallback);

        var media = navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraint);

        media.then(function(mediaStream){
            stream=mediaStream;
            var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            if(mediaType!=null){

                if(mediaType=="video/webm"){
                    mediactrl.src = url ? url.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
                    mediactrl.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {

                        mediactrl.play();
                    };
                }else{
                    mediactrl.src = url ? url.createObjectURL(stream) : stream;
                    mediactrl.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {

                        mediactrl.play();
                    }
                }
                $("#requestmedia").addClass("btndisabled faded-effect");
                $("#videocontrol").removeClass("btndisabled").prop("disabled",false);
                $("#mediaerror").html(string).css({"display":"block","color":"#003666"});
            }

        });

        media.catch(function(err){
            errorCallback(err);
        });
    }

}



function startRecording(stream){

    /*
    if (typeof MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported == 'function'){
        if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=vp9')) {
                var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'};
        } else if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=vp8')) {
                var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8'};
        }

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, options);

    }else{
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream); //Default codec for browser
    }
    */
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    mediaRecorder.start(10);


    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e){
        chunks.push(e.data);
    };

    mediaRecorder.onerror = function(e){
        console.log("Error: "+e)    
    };

    mediaRecorder.onstop = function(){
        var blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: mediaType});
        chunks = [];
        var mediaURL = (window.webkitURL || window.URL).createObjectURL(blob);
        sendFileToServer(blob);
        //console.log(mediaURL);
    };



}

function errorCallback(error){
  console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
}

function releaseDevice(){

    if(stream && stream.stop){
        //stream.stop();

        if(mediaType=="video/webm"){
        stream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();  
        stream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
        }else{
        stream.getAudioTracks()[0].stop();
        }


    }

    stream=null;
}
```

Comment: [IE doesn't support StreamAPI](https://caniuse.com/#feat=stream)

Comment: Check the link i put under, it's a workaround

Comment: Yeah, prolly their `.swf` is the workaround as a fallback. Have you tried it in your code?

Comment: Yes, however I can't implement it :\ That's why I am asking